# Ignoring line *: WARNING: PHP Settings must be modified... Magento

Tags: php, magento

Hi I have this problem on my Magento webshop. I am getting lots of these.

> Ignoring line 41: WARNING: PHP Settings must be modified through your PHP script or DataZone Control Panel, referer: http://test.domain.com/
>   test.domain.com [Sun Dec 21 03:42:24 2014] [alert] [client 000.00.00.00] /root/path/to/www.domain.com/htdocs_new/.htaccess: Ignoring line 47: WARNING: PHP Settings must be modified through your PHP script or DataZone Control Panel, referer: http://test.domain.com/
>   test.domain.com [Sun Dec 21 03:42:24 2014] [alert] [client 000.00.00.00] /root/path/to/www.domain.com/htdocs_new/.htaccess: Ignoring line 57: WARNING: PHP Settings must be modified through your PHP script or DataZone Control Panel, referer: http://test.domain.com/
>   test.domain.com [Sun Dec 21 03:42:24 2014] [alert] [client 000.00.00.00] /root/path/to/www.domain.com/htdocs_new/.htaccess: Ignoring line 62: WARNING: PHP Settings must be modified through your PHP script or DataZone Control Panel, referer: http://test.domain.com/

What could cause it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento .htaccess file modifies some php settings directly in .htaccess file. Looks like you are using a shared hosting, or you dont have permissions to change php settings in your .htaccess file, therefore you are getting those warnings.

Remove all those lines from .htaccess file which are modifying php settings, and make the modifications in your php.ini file. How to modify your php.ini file, contact your hosting provider for this.

Thank you